# Publishing immutable object references in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I am reading "Java Concurency in Practice" by Brian Goetz, and have a question about immutable object publication.

In section 3.5.5 it states:

> *Immutable objects* can be published through any mechanism.
> *Effectively immutable objects* must be safely published;

As an example for my question:

```
// assume Holder is immutable

public class Test {
    public static Holder holder = null;
}
```

Suppose a thread executes the statement:

```
Test.holder = new Holder(42);
```

Does this change (i.e. both the reference and the immutable Holder object together) become visible to other threads?

It would seem the semantics, if I'm understanding the textbook correctly, are similar to volatile variables in the sense that the update to the `Test.holder` member specifically is visible to other threads immediately?

Comment: `Test.holder` is not immutable. `Holder` instances are immutable, but `Test.holder` is not a `Holder` instance. It is a mutable _variable_ that either can be `null`, or can contain a reference to an immutable `Holder` instance. If, as the comment says, `Holder` is immutable,  that means you cannot change the fields (member variables) of any `Holder` instance; but you _can_ change `Test.holder` to refer to a different `Holder` instance at any time.

Comment: No.  The write to `holder` is an ordinary, non-volatile write, and any read of the field is an ordinary, non-volatile read.  Therefore there is no _happens-before_ between the write in one thread and the read in another.

Comment: I think you are confused because there's a variant of this -- the initialize-on-demand-holder-idiom -- where `holder` is final and the value is computed in a field initializer (or static initializer.)  In this case, the final field safety guarantees ensure that actions performed as part of class initialization are visible through static final fields of the class.  But those are not in play for an ordinary write when `holder` is not final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modification made to the reference variable `Test.holder` is not guaranteed to be seen by other threads immediately. To ensure this, you have to declare it as `volatile`. Then, writes to `Test.holder` become visible immediately.

What is meant in the text is that if you initialized the `Test.holder` with a `new Holder(42)` instead of `null` and never changed it, then all threads would see that `Holder(42)` object.

Comment: I thought this as well, but the text explicitly mentions safe publication mechanisms (such as volatile) must be used for _effectively mutable objects_ (those that are not technically immutable, but whose state will not be modified after publication).  In contrast, it mentions _immutable objects_ as not having this requirement.

Comment: I believe the relevant distinction is about _visibility_: you can safely publish an object without it being immediately visible.

Comment: The point is, there is no guaranty whether the new reference will be seen by another thread, but *if* another thread happens to see the new reference, it will see the immutable (having only final fields) object in a consistent state whereas mutable or only effectively immutable objects may be seen in an inconsistent state.